# when i set an array value to anything other than 0 it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property "1 - 15"' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

i'm currently attempting to make a map generator but in the section where i randomly set pieces to be land , if i set them to anything other than 0 or "" it returns

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property "1 - 15"' of undefined"

(it doesn't return "1-15", it just returns a number between 1 and the arrays length (which is 15) when it is run)

```
//lets every block surrounding a land peice have a 1 in 3 chance of making more land
for(let y = 0; y < proxy.length; y++){
    for(let x = 0; x < proxy[y].length; x++){
        if(proxy[y][x] != 0){

            for(let i = -1; i <= 1; i++){
                for(let j = -1; j <= 1; j++){

                    let run = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

                    if(run == 0){
                        proxy[y + i][x + j] = "o"
                    }

                }
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

(full code)
https://jsfiddle.net/2q9rz38x/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify this problem for a second. The actual error you see is because you are accessing `proxy[A][B]`, where `proxy[A]` is undefined, and hence you get `Cannot set property B of undefined`.

Think for a second what possible values `A` can get. `A` is `y + i` in your code. You are looping `y` from `0` to `proxy.length - 1`, and you are looping `i` from `-1` to `1`.

So, the possible range for `y + i` will be `-1` to `proxy.length`. That is 1 item more in both directions than it should be! (You'll agree that `proxy[-1]` is probably undefined, same for `proxy[proxy.length]`...)

The same goes for `x + j` of course, but this would not throw an error because it would just write new properties at `proxy[something][-1]` for example, which is probably not intended but is valid JavaScript.

Therefore, you'll either have to change the loop or constrain the values. Since this is a map generator on a fixed-size map, I'd guess it's more logical to constrain the result. So, you'd do something like this:

```js
if (
  y + i >= 0 &&
  y + i < proxy.length &&
  x + j >= 0 &&
  x + j < proxy[y + i].length
) {
  proxy[y + i][x + j] = "o"
}
```

...or, alternatively:

```js
if ((y + i) in proxy && (x + j) in proxy[y + i]) {
  proxy[y + i][x + j] = "o"
}
```